# 301 Issues with HTTPS only

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect an old domain to a new one. I am having all sorts of issues.

This is my .htaccess file which has the redirects

```
# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mjvandco.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mjvandco.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The old domain is mjvandco.co.uk. The following URLs are not working:

https://www.mjvandco.co.uk/
https://mjvandco.co.uk/

This one is redirecting fine:
http://mjvandco.co.uk/
http://www.mjvandco.co.uk/

I want them all to redirect to:

https://www.mjvandco.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those conditions before forcing 301 redirection to your URL with https. You only need this;

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mjvandco\.co\.uk 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mjvandco.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the only URL that now is not right is this one: http://www.mjvlaw.co.uk/. I used [this site](https://httpstatus.io/)
<br/>
https://mjvlaw.co.uk - ok<br/>
http://mjvlaw.co.uk - ok<br/>
http://www.mjvlaw.co.uk - not work<br/>
https://www.mjvlaw.co.uk - fine<br/>
<br/>
However, when I do the same for the old domain it all works.
<br/>
https://www.mjvandco.co.uk<br/>
https://mjvandco.co.uk<br/>
http://mjvandco.co.uk<br/>
http://www.mjvandco.co.uk<br/>
<br/>
They all redirect to https://wwwmjvlaw.co.uk
<br/>
Both URLs are pointed to the same webspace too. Is that OK?